# react native Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, merge-conflict-resolution

After adding react-native-admob library I got next error message

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>           is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>           Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

I try to add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" as suggested but build still fail.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.4.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.4",
    "mobx": "^5.9.4",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",
    "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.6.5",
    "react-native-pose": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.9.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rntodo"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-admob')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.rntodo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am not sure from where I have dependencies androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
Please advise me how to resolve manifest merge conflict. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The lib refers to some files and classes from the old Android support library. Since 0.60, AndroidX support library is used instead of android-support. It means all dependencies must rely on it.

Fortunately, a tool exists to convert the lib to the new format. It's called jetifier: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jetifier. You can use it and add it as a yarn/npm post install script so that it's applied to all the node_modules dependencies after each yarn/npm installs.

Another alternative exists for your library as another author reported that he created a fork of react-native-admob and updated it to the latest AndroidX support library, see https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/459

Comment: you say from v0.60 react native use androidX, but I use v0.59.5

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jetifier to solve this because react native have now moved on to 0.60+ which supports androidX dependencies and most of the libraries are doing so catch up with react native.

1. npm install jetifier
2. npx jetify
3. In your gradle.properties add

`android.enableJetifier=true`

`android.useAndroidX=true`

Comment: but I use react-native v0.59.5

Comment: Still if using firebase etc, you might need to do that. Create a new branch and then try resolving that. If it goes good then its fine else you can revert. :)

Comment: I used androidx and jetify, build is success but app is crashing with no logs.

Comment: See in logcat of the android emulator what is the error.